# Data Paging with specific layout

Tags: asp.net, paging

I am trying to use data paging (not custom data paging - just normal inefficient paging) for about max 125 records, over 5 pages, 25 records per page. But most samples out there seem to be using a gridview or a datagrid, however I want each record to look like this:

```
Record 1 Title
Record 1 Description
Record 1 Time:     Record 1 Contact:

Record 2 Title
Record 2 Description
Record 2 Time:     Record 2 Contact:
```

etc etc, however with grids they result is like a table with bound fields for each column so I can't display it like that using paging, I thought of using a Repeater however I think I will need to use viewstate for that as it doesn't have paging built in and don't want to use ViewState as I have disabled this - can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.aspx) or a [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> The Repeater control is a basic
>   templated data-bound list. It has no
>   built-in layout or styles, so you must
>   explicitly declare all layout,
>   formatting, and style tags within the
>   control's templates.